# Pine Script warning

Tags: pine-script

I'm having problems understanding this. Why is the first example giving a warning but not the second?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test warning", overlay = true)

float h = na
h(i) =>
    high[i]

if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to 10
        h := h(i)

plot(close)
```

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test warning", overlay = true)

float h = na
if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to 10
        h := high[i]

plot(close)
```

Comment: what is the warning?

Comment: It's `The function 'h' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope`

Comment: because each call of a function is considered a separate instance, it is not paying attention to what is in the function. Whereas the other is a simple historical reference. The pine compiler doesn't look inside your function to determine if there would be a problem.